# What is the difference between libraries like C++/PDCurses and SFML?

Tags: c++, 2d

I have read that PDCurses is a library that can be used to create 2D games however SFML is also a library but they are not in the same category I presume according to what I have read:

"The system terminal is a part of your operating system which allows communicating with the computer using text. If you choose to do this, it is also a good idea to use a library — but now, you use a library for creating programs working in the terminal, rather than a game library. Here, the most popular choice is Curses"

Can somebody explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curses is for text, SFML for pixels.

PDCurses is a library specifically for creating text-based pseudo-graphical interfaces which visualize everything using fixed-width characters. You can use if for games like the original NetHack:

[image: Nethack]

Or the more recent Dwarf Fortress:
[image: Dwarf Fortress]
(although neither of those projects actually uses Curses anymore. They both switched to sprite-based libraries which simulate the look of Curses console applications).

SFML, on the other hand, is a library which allows you (among other features) to load sprites from image files and place those image sprites on the screen. This makes it a feasible option for 2d games which look like they were made after 1990.

Comment: @Phillip so what are the advantages in using PDCurses library over SFML library? What is the boundary between them?

Comment: @CemTuğanlı The first is for text, the second for pixels.

Comment: @Phillip or, what is the difference between using pure ASCII characters and using a PDCurses library?

Comment: Why don't you just read [the documentation of PDCurses](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/docs/README.md) and compare it to how [std::ostream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) works?